# How to see which watchers get called in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a parent component, with many nested children components inside.

A click on one of my children's components updates the route. The `route` property is watched on the parent component, and does some actions on change.

This can be extremely difficult to debug if I don't know which component contains the watcher. Is there a way to see which watchers get executed?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but you may use the devtools to see which components emit something.
[image]

On top of that, you could probably `console.log` in the `watch` or emit some additional payload to identify the component more easily.